# Unable to change Apple ID email

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I am trying to change the email address associated with my Apple ID.  However, whenever I try, I get an error message:

```
This email address is not available. Choose a different address.
```

How do I overcome this issue and change my Apple ID email address?

Comment: Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/334697/edit) the question to specify what steps did you try? You can also refer to the support document, [Change your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/HT202667) and verify if you missed any step.

Comment: That error message *suggests* that you are trying to change the email address associated with your AppleID to one that already exists. If the email you want ends with .icloud, .mac or .me that is likely the case. If so you'll have to pick another email address.